# How to calculate the range of angles at which a line will intersect a growing circle? Arc length?

Tags: geometry, circles

I am working on some simulation software in which I have an entity (**e**) that is spiralling around a particular point (**p**). As **e** continues to move around **p**, the radius of the circle that it is following increases at a constant rate- causing it to follow the 'spiral' line rather than a 'circle' line.

I am currently working on displaying the number of times that **e** has completed a full circuit of **p**. A full circuit is defined by the point at which **e** passes through the angle that it was at from **p** when it first started moving.

At the moment, I the initial radius of the circle that **e** will follow is being set by the user, and I am then increasing that radius as **e** moves around **p** using the following calculation:

```
m_currentRadius = m_currentRadius + (m_Velocity*(elapsedSIMTime/3600.0));
```

where `m_currentRadius` is the current radius of the circle that **e** is following, `m_Velocity` is the speed at which **e** is moving, and `elapsedSIMTime` is the duration of time (in minutes) for which the simulaion has been running.

I am then incrememnting the 'number of circuits flown' by 1 every time the following condition is met:

> if((current angle of **e** from **p** >= (original angle of **e** from **p** - 0.017)) && (current angle of **e** from **p** <= (original angle of **e** from **p** + 0.017)) && (the circuit number hasn't already been updated with this iteration of loop))`

The problem that I have with this condition, is that because it is being called several times every second (the number of times it will be called depends on the speed at which **e** is moving), as **e** continues to move around **p**, and its distance from **p** increases, this condition will be called more frequently (relative to the current angle of **e** from **p**).

Because of this, when the radius of the circle that **e** is currently following reaches a certain size, the condition that I am using to update the circuit number will be called/ performed more than once on the same circuit, and so will present an incorrect circuit number to the user.

I am aware that I will need to change the formula in the condition that I am using to check the angle of **e** from **p**, to account for the increase in the size of the radius of the circle... but I am unsure how to do this...

Basically, I need to change my formula to use a variable instead of the constant that I am currently using (0.017), and the value of this variable should decrease as the radius of the circle increases.

Effectively, I think I want to have a constant arc length, and calculate the range of angles that intersect this arc length depending on the size of the radius of the circle- because as the radius of the circle grows, the range of angles which intersect the defined arc will decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a constant arc length $a$, the angle (in radians) identified by this arc for a given radius $r$ is $\frac{a}{r}$. This angle tends to zero as $r$ increases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just to double check I understand this correctly- if for example, the arc starts at 0 degrees (i.e. due North), and extends clockwise around the circle for a distance/ arc length of 10, the angle at which the arc will end will be `10/r`? So by manipulating that formula, it would be correct to say that `a.r = 10`?

Comment: Also, would it then be correct to say that all of the angles 'covered' by the arc would be `0 <= x <= a/r` ?

Comment: Yes, the angle at which the arc ends is $10/r$ (measured in radians, and where $10$ is measured in the same units as $r$). As regards your second question, what do you mean exactly by "all of the angles covered by the arc"?

Comment: Sorry, by "all of the angles covered by the arc", I mean that `x` could be an angle of any value that lies between 0 and a/r.

Comment: Yes, all these angles are included between $0$ and $10/r$.